# JQuery run function on change and on delay

Tags: jquery

I found this function to delay a keyup callback, which works perfectly after the 3 seconds I have set it too.

```
function delay_callback(callback, ms) {
      var timer = 0;
      return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
          callback.apply(context, args);
        }, ms || 0);
      };
    }


$('#postcode').keyup(delay_callback(function (e) {
    do_postcode();
    validate_fields();
}, 3000));
```

So I also want to call it on change like this `$('#postcode').on('change',...` but that in addition to the delay makes it run on change and then 3 seconds later so its running twice.

My "onchange" code

```
$('#postcode').on('change', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    do_postcode();
    validate_fields();
});
```

How can I call the function both on change and after the delay, but not both.

So I want to cancel the delay if the input is changed

Comment: what is exactly your code with on change?

Comment: @Frenchy see above

Comment: could you show html code with id postcode

Answer (score 0):

If i understant your explanation, you want to trap both events but you just want to cancel delay when event change is detected ..

```
timer = -1;
function delay_callback(callback, ms) {

      return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
          callback.apply(context, args);
        }, ms || 0);
      };
    }

$('#postcode').keyup(delay_callback(function (e) {
    do_postcode();
    validate_fields();
}, 3000));

$('#postcode').on('change', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    do_postcode();
    validate_fields();
});
```

why not replaced keyup event by input event?

```
$('#postcode').on("input change", function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if(e.type == "change"){
    clearTimeout($this.data('timer'));//if you want to cancel the timeout
    do_postcode();
    validate_fields();
    return;
 }
  
  var delay = 3000; // 3 seconds delay after last input

  clearTimeout($this.data('timer'));
  $this.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
    do_postcode();
    validate_fields();

  }, delay));
});
```

Comment: so I just tried adding `e.stopPropagation();` to the above, and also inside `$('#postcode').on('change', function(e) {` but that still runs on change and then 3 seconds after

Comment: so, doing that with `$('#postcode').on('change', function(e) {` as well returns this in the console `Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function`

Comment: ignore that comment, i fixed that error but its still running after the 3 seconds when the `on`change` has picked up - https://pastebin.com/ZrHR3iuS

Comment: so, i want to run the function both after the delay (3 seconds) and also on change, but if it triggers the change, i want to cancel the delay. So for example, if i enter a value into the input and tab to the next input or click out of it, it'll run because of the `change` - at this point i dont need to run after the delay because it has already run

Comment: i dont understant why you don use the event input instead of keyup and change

Comment: I just tried that code, and its working, but it doesnt call the function immediately on change?

Comment: see my answer modified.  i dunno why you want to replay the both funtion when change, because input detect each change and play both functions

Comment: i don't want to run the function on both, it just needs to be one. so on change, it'll run the function and if the user remains in the input, it'll run after 3 seconds

Comment: the event change is only activated when user quit the input and if data have been modified.. so i dont understant the behavior of yout event..and without the html code its diffciult to undersatnt better...